# is my select statement right

Tags: php, mysql, select

Is this statement correct syntactically:

```
$query = "SELECT matric_no session course_name
              FROM main_table session
              WHERE main_table.matric_no = '$_POST[matric_no]'
                  AND session.session_name = '$_SESSION[session]'
                  AND session.course_name =  '$_SESSION[course_name]'";
$result = mysql_query($query) ;                       
$duplicates = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($duplicates = 1) {
    echo "you have dis in the database";
};
```

Comment: There's a great way to find out - Try it.

Comment: haha.. I did. And i got mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in c:........

Comment: Because the query is failing - Print out some errors with `mysql_error()` and you'll know why.

Comment: `session course_name` should be `session.course_name` in the select list

Comment: ...and the `if` statement? totally not correct.

Comment: @dotman14: For future reference, if you tried it and got an error message, it's helpful to state that in your question and provide the error message. It also gets you help faster.

Comment: @Jim H. How could this be written?

Comment: @Ken White...matric_no session course_name are all different table columns. In main_table and session respectively.

I got mysql_num_rows() expect parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in c:  at the point where i did $duplicates = mysql_num_rows($result);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some syntax problems in your query

if main_table and session are two different tables then it should be something like this.

```
"SELECT main_table.matric_no, session.course_name
          FROM main_table, session
          WHERE main_table.matric_no = '$_POST[matric_no]'
              AND session.session_name = '$_SESSION[session]'
              AND session.course_name =  '$_SESSION[course_name]'"
```

Comment: you should write "." when accessing any column from a table and also put a "," between two table names.

Comment: @Singh ... I was lacking in the basics. It has worked thank roe the help.

Comment: your welcome ! if you find any answer helpful, then you should accept the answer. it helps others reading your question to find right answer. (just a free advice :p ) Happy Coding. :)

Comment: okay ! I don't know about mobiles but if you access it using browser, there you will see a TICk (RIGHT TICK) sign, when you will mouse over on answer,  on the left side of the answer. Just click that of any answer you like.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need all the info in the **SELECT** to check if session is in database.

```
   $matricNo = $_POST[matric_no];
    $sessionName = $_ SESSION[session];
    $courseName = $_ SESSION[course_name];

//here you should use mysql_real_escape_string() for security
//like this $matricNo = mysql_real_escape_string($matricNo);

$query = "SELECT m.matric_no
          FROM main_table as m, session as s
          WHERE m.matric_no = '$matricNo' 
            AND s.session_name = '$sessionName'
            AND s.course_name = '$courseName'"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error()); 

$duplicates = mysql_num_rows($result); 

if ($duplicates > 0) { 
    echo "you have dis in the database"; 
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There are three problems:
1) Missing comma (already pointed out) in the select statement.
2) With the first problem solved it should then generate a Cartesian product because you didn't join between the two tables. You should have something like this:

```
SELECT
  m.matric_no,
  s.course_name
FROM
  main_table mt,
  session s
WHERE
      mt.[SOMECOLUMN] = s.[ANOTHERCOLUMN]
  AND mt.matric_no    = '$_POST[matric_no]'
  AND s.session_name  = '$_SESSION[session]'
  AND s.course_name   = '$_SESSION[course_name]'"
```

or (if ANSI-style joins are supported) this:

```
SELECT
  m.matric_no,
  s.course_name
FROM
  main_table mt
  JOIN
    session s ON (mt.[SOMECOLUMN] = s.[ANOTHERCOLUMN])
WHERE
      mt.matric_no   = '$_POST[matric_no]'
  AND s.session_name = '$_SESSION[session]'
  AND s.course_name  = '$_SESSION[course_name]'"
```

3) The query is open to a SQL injection attack. NEVER pass variables in without first cleansing them (at least variables that can be altered by the user). If at all possible use query parameters to take care of the issue. If this is not an option, simply cleanse the variables by removing characters such as single-quotes that can be used to alter the query. It has been a while since I have used MySQL, so maybe there is some magic I am unaware of that will take care of this for you, but I don't see how that would be possible. UPDATE: Do what hafichuk suggests above :-)

Comment: what options of database can i migrate to?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt it be:

```
$query = "SELECT main_table.matric_no, session.course_name
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you need to seriously reconsider is using unsanitized data from `$_POST` and `$_SESSION`. This is potentially a major security risk to your site as someone can fairly easily perform some [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

At a minimum you should be using [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

I would also look at migrating your code to use mysqli or PDO, as mysql is quite outdated.